# Java Regular Expression to .NET

Tags: java, .net, regex

I am trying to convert the following regular expression from Java to .NET:

```
    (?i:(?:([^\d,]+?)\W+\b((?:CA|SD|SC|CT|DC)\b)?\W*)?(\d{5}(?:[- ]\d{3,4})?)?)
```

When I run a match against the following string:

```
Mountain View, CA 94043
```

using a Pattern and Matcher object in Java, it populates four groups with the values:

```
    "Mountain View, CA 94043"
    "Mountain View"
    "CA"
    "94043"
```

However, in .NET, there are two matches.  The first match populates the four groups with these values:

```
    "Mountain "(there is a space on the end of group 0)
    "Mountain"
    ""
    ""
```

The second match populates the three groups with these values:

```
    "View, CA 94043"
    "View"
    "CA"
    "94043"
```

I also tried the expression using RegexBuddy using both the Java and .NET modes and in RegexBuddy, both modes work like the .NET version.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `^` to the beginning of your pattern, and add `$` to the end of it to match the beginning and end of the string, respectively. This will make the pattern match the entire string and produces your desired result:

```
string input = "Mountain View, CA 94043";
string pattern = @"^(?i:(?:([^\d,]+?)\W+\b((?:CA|SD|SC|CT|DC)\b)?\W*)?(\d{5}(?:[- ]\d{3,4})?)?)$";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
}
```

Since you didn't restrict the pattern to be an exact match, as above, it found partial matches, especially since some of your groups are completely optional. Thus, it considers "Mountain" a match, then considers "View, CA 94043" as the next match.

**EDIT:** as requested in the comments, I'll try to point out the differences between the Java and .NET regex approaches.

In Java the `matches()` method returns true/false if the pattern matches the whole string. Thus it doesn't require the pattern to be modified with boundary anchors or atomic zero-width assertions. In .NET there is no such equivalent method that will do this for you. Instead, you need to explicitly add either the `^` and `$` metacharacters, to match the start and end of the string or line, respectively, or the `\A` and `\z` metacharacters to do the same for the entire string. For a reference of .NET metacharacters check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). I'm not sure which set of anchors Java's `matches()` uses, although [this article](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/MatchExactly.html) suggests `\A` and `\z` are used.

Java's `matches()` returns a boolean, and .NET provides the [`Regex.IsMatch()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) to do the same thing (apart from the already discussed difference of matching the entire string). The .NET equivalent of Java's `find()` method is the [`Regex.Match()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx), which you can use in a loop to continue to find the next match. In addition, .NET offers a `Regex.Matches()` method that will do this for you, and returns a collection of successful matches. Depending on your needs and the input this might be fine, but for added flexibility you may want to check `Match.Success` in a loop and use the [`Match.NextMatch()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch.aspx) to keep looking for matches (an example of this is available in the `NextMatch` link).

Comment: I'll +1 if you add the difference between Java's `Matcher.matches` and .Net's `Regex.Match` methods

Comment: @CodeJockey updated my post. Feel free to suggest any corrections if I missed something.